# Generators' browsers support

Tags: javascript

I want to use the following code in my script, that will be attached to a couple of websites:

```
Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    var one = yield get('http://url1.com');
    // do something
    var two = yield get('http://url2.com');
    // do something
})().catch(function (errors) {
    // handle errors
});
```

The thing is that I can't use jQuery, nor any other libraries - it has to be clean JS, because only my script can be included, I can't include anything else, and I don't know what scripts will be available on those websites.

Also, it has to work under every browser.

Are generators and promises safe to use here?

Comment: No, they’re ES6. Only the ES5 standard is largely supported, currently.

Comment: That would depend on the client machines you need to support; if your users have any IE less than 11 (possibly 10) then I'd say "no," but I've not verified the versions of IE in which promises and generators were introduced. Or even if they have been.

Comment: *Also, it has to work under every browser* - This is going to be a huge problem considering once upon a time browsers didn't have JavaScript support. I'd advise you to define practical boundaries for your support base.

Answer (score 0):

No, Promises and Generators are part of the ECMASCRIPT-6 specification, and, aren't available for most of current browsers...

If you need to implement that, you may also have a look on what follows:

1. [List of es-6 tools](https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-tools)

Comment: So what's the point of using ES6, if most browsers don't support this?

Comment: The goal is to be up-to-date, of course, at the moment you need to use a transpiler that converts your es6 in es5... Do you know Babel?

Comment: But I still have to convert es6 to es5 inside just one script, without the ability to add other external scripts. Or some dynamic converter that will convert my minified js from es6 to es5 after pulling it on server.

Comment: In a normal deployment-flux you transpile before minify and don't push your build but just your source... You probably need to learn how to do deployments